# How I analyze jmeter reports. Where is the best tutorial available

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

How I analyze jmeter reports. Where is the best tutorial available

Answer (score 0):

If you already executed your test and generated [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) you should see some numbers in the statistics table.

These are so called [KPIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Performance_indicator), see [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) for the description on what do the metrics mean.

The next step would be detecting [KPI correlations](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/understanding-your-reports-part-2-kpi-correlations), like see the relationship between increasing number of users and the increasing response time or errors rate.

And the final step would be creating a [report](https://u-tor.com/topic/performance-testing-report) which normally consists of two parts:

1. Manager-friendly summary stating where the application meets [NFR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement), what is the saturation point, what is the first bottleneck, what are possible risks, etc.
2. Technical details with in-depth analysis of performance degradations including logs, slow database queries, profiler tool output interpretation, etc.